# eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Good Day,

I have a matrix of

\begin{bmatrix}
28 & 10\\ 
10 & 19
\end{bmatrix}

I have found the eigenvalues...

first eigenvalue (v1) : 24 + 5sqrt5 = rd off to 35.18

second eigenvalue (v2) : 24 - 5sqrt5 = rd off to -12.81

[image]

Following the page above,
if eigenvalue = 35.18, -6.18x+10y = 0 and 10x-16.18y=0
if eigenvalue = 12.82, 16.18x+10y = 0 and 10x+6.18y=0

How should I proceed from here to get the Eigenvector?

With egreg's help, I am able to derive to [(sqrt{5}+1)/2   1] and [(sqrt5-1)/2   1].

There's another part of the question as shown below:
[image]

This is my working currently:
[image]

Is my current working correct (before getting matrix of abcd)?

I have expanded to the following...
$\frac{Yn}{Xn} = \frac{[[(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}+(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}]+90[(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}+(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})(24-5\sqrt{5})^{n}]]}{[(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}+(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}]+90[(\frac{1-5\sqrt{5}}{2})(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}+(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})(24-5\sqrt{5})^{n}]}$

How can I simplify it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't round, if you can avoid it. Your matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
29 & 10 \\
10 & 19
\end{bmatrix}
whose characteristic polynomial is
$$
X^2 - 48X + 451
$$
The roots are given by the formula
$$
\frac{48\pm\sqrt{48^2-4\cdot 451}}{2}
$$
so they are $24+5\sqrt{5}$ and $25-5\sqrt{5}$, so you computed correctly. An eigenvector relative to $25+5\sqrt{5}$ is a non zero solution of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
29-(24+5\sqrt{5}) & 10 \\
10 & 19-(24+5\sqrt{5})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, since we know that only one equation is sufficient, because by definition of eigenvalue the matrix has rank less than $2$, we can simply solve
$$
(5-5\sqrt{5})x_1+10x_2=0
$$
or
$$
(1-\sqrt{5})x_1+2x_2=0
$$
We can obviously give any (non zero) value to $x_2$, so we set $x_2=1$ and so
$$
x_1=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-1}\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{5}+1}
=\frac{2(\sqrt{5}+1)}{5-1}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}
$$
and an eigenvector is
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\\[2ex]
1
\end{bmatrix}
Similarly for the other eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you take a look at my edits. I have added another portion of the question as I am trying to get the value of L but is struggling with due to the formula.

Comment: @user136154 $\mathbf{x}_n=PD^nP^{-1}\mathbf{x}_0$; this should pose no difficulty (except for computations).

Comment: I think I gotten PD^2P^-1X0 (in the screenshot) of my editted question. I tried expanding to get Yn/Xn which is...

Yn = (24+5sqrt5)^n+(24+5sqrt5)^n+90[((1-5sqrt5)/2)(24+5sqrt5)^n + ((sqrt5+1)/2)(24-5sqrt5)^n]


$Xn = ((sqrt5 +1)/2)(24+(5sqrt5))^n + ((sqrt5-1)/2)(24+5sqrt5)^n + 90[((sqrt+5)/2)((1-sqrt5)/2)(24+(5sqrt5))^n + ((sqrt5-1)/2)((sqrt5+1)/2)(24-5sqrt5)^n]$

Not sure how to simply it to Yn / Xn. Sorry, I don't know how to do formatting.

Comment: Tried formatting... $\frac{Yn}{Xn} = \frac{[[(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}+(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}]+90[(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}+(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})(24-5\sqrt{5})^{n}]]}{[(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}+(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}]+90[(\frac{1-5\sqrt{5}}{2})(24+5\sqrt{5})^{n}+(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})(24-5\sqrt{5})^{n}]}$